# How to merge a collection of collections in Linq

Tags: linq, collections, linq-to-objects

I would like to be able to fusion an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` into `IEnumerable<T>` (i.e. merge all individual collections into one). The `Union` operators only applies to two collections. Any idea?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try

```
var it = GetTheNestedCase();
return it.SelectMany(x => x);
```

SelectMany is a LINQ transformation which essentially says "For Each Item in a collection return the elements of a collection".  It will turn one element into many (hence SelectMany).  It's great for breaking down collections of collections into a flat list.

Comment: LINQ never fails to surprise me with what it can do out of the box. :)

Comment: Aahhh....! Same voice, LINQ never disappoints.

Answer (score 16):

```
var lists = GetTheNestedCase();
return
    from list in lists
    from element in list
    select element;
```

is another way of doing this using C# 3.0 query expression syntax.